# can I call the apis in observable in a certain sequence/order

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

I am learning `angular` `Observable` topic. I was trying to call apis inside Observable and hoping that they will run in an order in which I have stated them.

Below is my component class code:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flav4',
  templateUrl: './flav4.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flav4.component.css']
})
export class Flav4Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  orderStatus!: any;
  data!: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private httpcli: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = new Observable(observer => {
      this.httpcli.get("http://localhost:9898/api/orderStart", { headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }).subscribe(data => {
        console.warn(data);
        this.orderStatus = data;
        observer.next(this.orderStatus);

      });
      this.httpcli.get("http://localhost:9898/api/orderWait", { headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }).subscribe(data => {
        console.warn(data);
        this.orderStatus = data;
        observer.next(this.orderStatus);

      });
      this.httpcli.get("http://localhost:9898/api/orderComplete", { headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }).subscribe(data => {
        console.warn(data);
        this.orderStatus = data;
        observer.next(this.orderStatus);

      });
    });
    this.data.subscribe(val => this.orderStatus = val);
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }
}
```

I was expecting console output to be

```
{"status": "orderStarted"}
{"status": "orderWaiting"}
{"status": "orderCompleted"}
```

However I got below output

```
{"status": "orderStarted"}
{"status": "orderCompleted"}
{"status": "orderWaiting"}
```

What should I change in this code in order to get desired output i.e to run APIs in a certain order or sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour as HTTP requests are asynchronous.

You can try chaining them with `mergeMap` also known as flatmap from RxJS library. I suggest you take a look at the behaviours as well.

Something like this as reference

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flav4',
  templateUrl: './flav4.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flav4.component.css']
})
export class Flav4Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  orderStatus!: any;
  data!: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private httpcli: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = this.httpcli.get("http://localhost:9898/api/orderStart", { headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }).pipe(
      mergeMap(orderStart => {
        console.warn(orderStart);
        this.orderStatus = orderStart;
        return this.httpcli.get("http://localhost:9898/api/orderWait", { headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } });
      }),
      mergeMap(orderWait => {
        console.warn(orderWait);
        this.orderStatus = orderWait;
        return this.httpcli.get("http://localhost:9898/api/orderComplete", { headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } });
      })
    );
    this.data.subscribe(orderComplete => {
      console.warn(orderComplete);
      this.orderStatus = orderComplete;
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }
}
```

Comment: `mergeMap` and `behaviors` Ok, noted. I am glad to know this new concept 'mergeMap' in your given solution. Thank You!